# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm having this crash when running on a device where the os cannot find the CocoaPods frameworks

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire
```

I have a app target and a framework target in my app and Alamofire is used only in the framework target. The podfile looks like this

```
use_frameworks!

target 'TVTest' do
    pod 'SDWebImage', :git => 'https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage', :commit => '30e9e0b516cca03d9f2abe75a91512d75b846406'
end

target 'TVTestKit' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.2'
end
```

If I add the Alamofire as a pod to the app target, it works fine but that's not what I want to do. I would have to do that for all the pods that my framework uses.

What is a correct way to use CocoaPods in a Framework target?